# jq: selecting a subset of keys from an object

Tags: json, select, key, subset, jq

Given an input json string of keys from an array, return an object with only the entries that had keys in the original object and in the input array.

I have a solution but I think that it isn't elegant (`{($k):$input[$k]}` feels especially clunky...) and that this is a chance for me to learn.

```
jq -n '{"1":"a","2":"b","3":"c"}'   \
    | jq --arg keys '["1","3","4"]' \
    '. as $input 
     | ( $keys | fromjson )
     | map( . as $k
          | $input
          | select(has($k))
          | {($k):$input[$k]}
          )
     | add'
```

Any ideas how to clean this up?

I feel like [Extracting selected properties from a nested JSON object with jq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29259249/extracting-selected-properties-from-a-nested-json-object-with-jq) is a good starting place but i cannot get it to work.

Comment: It wasn't clear from the documentation that I could use ( ) on the rhs of the == statement via the `select(.key == ("1","3","4"))`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

the inside operator works for most of time; however, I just found the inside operator has side effect, sometimes it selected keys not desired, suppose input is `{ "key1": val1, "key2": val2, "key12": val12 }` and select by `inside(["key12"])` it will select both `"key1"` and `"key12"`

use the in operator if need an exact match: like this will select `.key2` and `.key12` only

```
jq 'with_entries(select(.key | in({"key2":1, "key12":1})))'
```

because the in operator checks key from an object only (or index `exists?` from an array), here it has to be written in an object syntax, with desired keys as keys, but values do not matter; the use of in operator is not a perfect one for this purpose, I would like to see the Javascript ES6 includes API's reverse version to be implemented as jq builtin

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

```
jq 'with_entries(select(.key | included(["key2", "key12"])))'
```

to check an item `.key` is `included?` from an array

Comment: Shouldn't this have been an edit to your other answer?

Comment: but can I have two answers on the same thread? just because there're two different approaches

Comment: You can, but usually you want to put caveats to an approach in the same answer that suggests it, so no one has to read the entire Q+A before deciding on a suitable approach. And fairly similar approaches can often be combined into one answer.

Answer (score 39):

solution with inside check:

```
jq 'with_entries(select([.key] | inside(["key1", "key2"])))'
```

Comment: FYI, this returns any entry that starts with `key1` or `key2`, so also `key1234` and `key22`.

Answer (score 12):

If you are sure that all keys in the input array are present in the original object, you can use the [object construction](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#object-construction) shortcut.

```bash
$ echo '{"1":"a","2":"b","3":"c"}' | jq '{"1", "3"}'
{
  "1": "a",
  "3": "c"
}
```

Numbers should be quoted to force `jq` to interpret them as keys instead of literals. In the case of keys not resembling a number, quotes are not needed:

```bash
$ echo '{"key1":"a","key2":"b","key3":"c"}' | jq '{key1, key3}'
{
  "key1": "a",
  "key3": "c"
}
```

Adding a non-existent key will yield a null value, unlikely what OP wanted:

```bash
$ echo '{"1":"a","2":"b","3":"c"}' | jq '{"1", "3", "4"}'
{
  "1": "a",
  "3": "c",
  "4": null
}
```

but those can be filtered out:

```bash
$ echo '{"1":"a","2":"b","3":"c"}' | jq '{"1", "3", "4"} | with_entries(select(.value != null))'
{
  "1": "a",
  "3": "c"
}
```

Although this answer doesn't receive a valid input json array as OP asked, I find it useful for just filtering some keys you know are present.

An example use case: get `aud` and `iss` from a JWT. The following is very succinct:

```bash
echo "jwt-as-json" | jq '{aud, iss}'
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use this filter:

```
with_entries(
    select(
        .key as $k | any($keys | fromjson[]; . == $k)
    )
)
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is some additional clarification

For the input object `{"key1":1, "key2":2, "key3":3}` I would like to drop all keys that are not in the set of desired keys `["key1","key3","key4"]`

```
 jq -n --argjson desired_keys '["key1","key3","key4"]'  \
       --argjson input '{"key1":1, "key2":2, "key3":3}' \
    ' $input
    | with_entries(
          select(
              .key == ($desired_keys[])
          )
       )'
```

`with_entries` converts `{"key1":1, "key2":2, "key3":3}` into the following array of key value pairs and maps the select statement on the array and then turns the resulting array back into an object.

Here is the inner object in the `with_entries` statement.

```
[
  {
    "key": "key1",
    "value": 1
  },
  {
    "key": "key2",
    "value": 2
  },
  {
    "key": "key3",
    "value": 3
  }
]
```

we can then select the keys from this array that meet our criteria.

This is where the magic happens... here is a look at whats going on in the middle of this command. The following command takes the expanded array of values and turns them into a list of objects that we can select from.

```
jq -cn '{"key":"key1","value":1}, {"key":"key2","value":2}, {"key":"key3","value":3}
      | select(.key == ("key1", "key3", "key4"))'
```

This will yield the following result

```
{"key":"key1","value":1}
{"key":"key3","value":3}
```

The with entries command can be a little tricky but its easy to remember that it takes a filter and is defined as follows

```
def with_entries(f): to_entries|map(f)|from_entries;
```

This is the same as

```
def with_entries(f): [to_entries[] | f] | from_entries;
```

The other part of the question that confuses people is the multiple matches on the right hand side of the `==`

Consider the following command. We see the output is an outer production of all the left hand lists and the right hand lists.

```
jq -cn '1,2,3| . == (1,1,3)'
true
true
false
false
false
false
false
false
true
```

If that predicate is in a select statement, we keep the input when the predicate is true. Note you can duplicate the inputs here too.

```
jq -cn '1,2,3| select(. == (1,1,3))'
1
1
3
```

Answer (score 7):

Jeff's answer has a couple of unnecessary inefficiencies, both of which are addressed by the following, on the assumption that `--argjson keys` is used instead of `--arg keys`:

```
with_entries( select( .key as $k | $keys | index($k) ) )
```

Even better, if your jq has `IN`:

```
with_entries(select(.key | IN($keys[])))
```

Comment: thats clever. avoids going through the entire outer product of input keys and desired keys.