# Using jq to extract specific property values and output on a single line

Tags: json, jq

I've this ElasticSearch snapshot output and would like to reduce it to print, on a single line, from each `snapshot` the values of the  `end_time_in_millis` and `snapshot` property separate by a space:

```
1429609790767 snapshot_1
1429681169896 snapshot_2
```

Basically the output of

- `cat  data | jq '.snapshots[].end_time_in_millis'` and
- `cat  data | jq '.snapshots[].snapshot'`

but combined on one line.

I was looking at `map` but couldn't make out how to apply it; also reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29259249/extracting-selected-properties-from-a-nested-json-object-with-jq) I tried:

```
cat data  | jq '.snapshots[] | map(. |= with_entries( select( .key == ( "snapshot") ) ) )'
```

But that produces lots of errors and `null` output.

The data:

```
{
  "snapshots": [
    {
      "shards": {
        "successful": 1,
        "failed": 0,
        "total": 1
      },
      "failures": [],
      "snapshot": "snapshot_1",
      "indices": [
        "myindex1"
      ],
      "state": "SUCCESS",
      "start_time": "2015-04-21T09:45:47.041Z",
      "start_time_in_millis": 1429609547041,
      "end_time": "2015-04-21T09:49:50.767Z",
      "end_time_in_millis": 1429609790767,
      "duration_in_millis": 243726
    },
    {
      "shards": {
        "successful": 1,
        "failed": 0,
        "total": 1
      },
      "failures": [],
      "snapshot": "snapshot_2",
      "indices": [
        "myindex1"
      ],
      "state": "SUCCESS",
      "start_time": "2015-04-22T05:36:02.333Z",
      "start_time_in_millis": 1429680962333,
      "end_time": "2015-04-22T05:39:29.896Z",
      "end_time_in_millis": 1429681169896,
      "duration_in_millis": 207563
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use this filter:

```
.snapshots[] | "\(.end_time_in_millis) \(.snapshot)"
```

This builds up a string for each of the snapshots consisting of the end time and the snapshot name.

Just make sure you use the `-r` option to get the raw output.

Comment: Perfect and thanks for the quick answer. I didn't notice http://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Stringinterpolationfoo somehow

Comment: Yep, that helped me, thank you. I needed a way to extract values from streamed JSON-L (one JSON object per line) and format them in a way that a legacy `awk`-using script could consume.